# Pass Rails model method to React front end

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

I have a Project model that is not associated to a TimesheetItem model. I've a simple method that returns query result from TimesheetItems.

```
  def project_timesheet_items
    TimesheetItem.where("project_group_name LIKE ?", "%#{self.group_name}%")
  end
```

I want to grab the results of this method and pass them as props to the project show page.

In my show.json.jbuilder file

```
project ||= @project
json.extract! project, :id, :name, :confidence_level
...
json.set! 'project_timesheet_items' do
  json.partial! partial: 'api/v1/project_timesheet_items/show', collection: 
  project.project_timesheet_items, as: :project_timesheet_items
end
```

And the show partial is

```
project_timesheet_item ||= @project_timesheet_item
json.extract! project_timesheet_item, :id, :project_group_name, :pay_type, :last_name, 
:first_name
```

But they're not showing up as props in the component.

Comment: Why don't you have an actual foreign key association between the two models so that you don't  have to look them up with `LIKE` which is extremely inefficient?

Comment: You will need to show us how you’re attempting to render the React component.